# Does Rust has a data type for encoding side effects as pure values?

Tags: rust, functional-programming, io, side-effects

I am doing some exercise from the book [Grokking Functional Programming](https://www.manning.com/books/grokking-functional-programming), the origin code examples are written in Scala, and I want to rewrite it with Rust and [Rakulang](https://raku.org).

In Scala's cats effect library, there is a type call IO, which is a data type for encoding side effects as pure values, capable of expressing both synchronous and asynchronous computations.

The following code print "hey!" twice:

```scala
import cats.effect.IO
import cats.effect.unsafe.implicits.global

object TestApp extends App {
  val program: IO[Unit] = for {
    _ <- IO.println("hey!")
    _ <- IO.println("hey!")
  } yield ()
  program.unsafeRunSync()
}
```

The code can be run in the [Scala playground.](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/eT3Qk9FkQ0WjED1lh1Z42Q)

So how to do it with Rust?

Comment: You can always encode a side effect as a pure value simply by having a side-effecting-function as a value (Fn or one of its siblings in Rust). Now if you want to impose some discipline on using side effects, you normally wrap that function in an opaque type such that it only can be used in limited ways. Say, you can never call such a function directly, but you can compose two such functions, and you can also lift a normal function to become a side-effecting one... oops, we have invented the IO monad...

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI Thank you for your detailed explanation, I can probably understand what you mean, but the concept of monad is too difficult for me, if possible, can you give out a simple example.

Comment: You don't actually need to know what a monad is before you can use IO. Just ignore the last sentence. I will try to cobble up a very simple implementation of IO in Rust later.

Comment: Well apparently I'm not fluent in Rust, I tried to code up something and got lost in a maze of lifetimes. Will try again but don't know how long it will take me.

Comment: It doesn't matter. I just want to explore the possibilities of Rust in functional programming, especially when dealing with side effects.

Comment: So [here](https://godbolt.org/z/sev1T5nq1) is my feeble attempt. Inside `main`, all the named variables are pure functional values with no side effects. They *encode* actions with side effects but do not *perform* them. The last line does all the IO and has all the side effects. The logic of the last action is not too complicated: read a string from stdin, repeat it twice, then write it to stdout; and then write another (constant) string to stdout. But it can be made arbitrarily complex by chaining (binding) more actions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Would you make it an answer that I can accept as an answer?

Comment: Answer added, enjoy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rust is not a functional language and doesn't have primitives or library facilities one would expect in a pure functional language. But we can make our own. How useful will they be in practice? Not much probably. Nevertheless it could be an enlightening exercise.

Below is an implementation of an UI type that looks more or less like Haskell's and perhaps Scala's IO. I am not an experienced Rust user and the lifetimes are probably all over the place, but I hope you will find it useful anyway.

```
use std::io;
use std::io::Write;

struct MyIo<'life, A: 'life> {
    run: Box<dyn FnOnce()->io::Result<A> + 'life>
}

fn unit_io<'life, A: 'life>(a: A)->MyIo<'life, A> {
    MyIo{run:Box::new(move||Ok(a))}
}

fn map_io<'life, A: 'life, B: 'life, Func: FnOnce(A)->B + 'life>(my_io: MyIo<'life, A>, func: Func) -> MyIo<'life, B>{
    MyIo{run:Box::new(move||
            match (my_io.run)() {
                Ok(x) => Ok(func(x)),
                Err(e) => Err(e)
            }
        )
    }
} 

fn bind_io<'life, A: 'life, B: 'life, Func: FnOnce(A)->MyIo<'life, B> + 'life>
    (my_io: MyIo<'life, A>, func: Func)->MyIo<'life, B> {
        MyIo{run:Box::new(move||
            match (my_io.run)() {
                Ok(x) => (func(x).run)(),
                Err(e) => Err(e)
            }
          )
        }
}

fn run_io<'life, A>(my_io: MyIo<'life, A>)->io::Result<A> {
    (my_io.run)()
}
```

A keen reader will recognise basic monadic operations `unit` and `bind`, and a functorial `map`, but you don't need to know what a monad is in order to use them. It is quite simple:

```
- unit: take a normal value and pretend it's an IO operation (it does no IO, but an empty set is still a set)
- map: take an IO operation that returns a value, and produce an IO operation that returns a transformed value
- bind: chain two IO operations together
```

With these primitives one can produce arbitrarily complex values that can do IO, without actually doing any IO while building them. When a value is built, `run_io` executes all its actions, chained one to another and intertwined with regular non-IO computations.

These building blocks would be useless without having primitive operations that do actual IO. You can chain two operations all you want, but in the end of the day you need something that reads and writes files. Below are two simple operations that do that, wrapped in an IO type. Any IO (or, more generally, side-effecting) operation can be wrapped this way.

```
fn my_read_string()->MyIo<'static, String> {
    MyIo{run: Box::new(move||std::io::read_to_string(io::stdin()))}
}

fn my_write_string(s: String)->MyIo<'static, ()> {
    MyIo{run: Box::new(move||(io::stdout().write_all(s.as_bytes())))}
}
```

Finally a test driver that exercises all of the above operations:

```
fn concat_me(a: String)->String {
    format!("{}:{}\n", a, a)
}

fn main() {

    // 1: read a string from stdin, double it, write it back to stdout
    let input = my_read_string();
    let doppio = map_io(input, concat_me);
    let output = bind_io(doppio, my_write_string);

    // 2: write a constant string to stdout
    let s = "hello monad".into();
    let lifted = unit_io(s);
    let output2 = bind_io(lifted, my_write_string);

    // do 1 then 2
    let all_io = bind_io(output, move |_|output2);

    let _ = run_io(all_io);
}
```

The last line is the one responsible for doing all the IO.